# flex mobile itemrender button when click button on list some time click button some time click list

Tags: actionscript-3

i have 2 event 
one is list change
one is button click

I want to click button but sometimes click list item
how to fix , thanks

[image http://img.my.csdn.net/uploads/201112/21/0_1324478869TXbz.gif](http://img.my.csdn.net/uploads/201112/21/0_1324478869TXbz.gif)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:IconItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"  
                labelField="title" 
                messageField="message" 
                iconField="ico" 
                iconWidth="64" 
                iconHeight="64"
                initialize="init()">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import spark.components.Button;
        private var delButton:Button;
        private function init():void{
            if(!delButton){
                delButton=new Button();
                delButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,handleClick);
                delButton.x=this.parent.width-70;
                delButton.y=20;
                delButton.height=30;
                delButton.width=50;
                delButton.label="aa";
                this.addChild(delButton);
            }
        }
        private function handleClick(event:MouseEvent):void{

        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
</s:IconItemRenderer>
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't use flex components and I'm not sure exactly how you add childs to them but the general idea is that you draw transparent rects on the top of the components that are not overlaping and add event listeners to those rects instead of to components directly - that way you won't miss your button.